# Suppressing empty fields in crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports

Suppressing lines in a cross tab crystal report

We currently have a cross tab report having a summary with 4 fields placed in a single section, sequentially one below the other.

If one of the fields are blank for e.g. 4 fields are named as f1, f2, f3, and f4 if f2 is blank we need to suppress this section to displaying a total of 3 lines.
I.e. displaying fields f1, f3, f4.

Is this possible in crystal reports 10.0. This would save the display space of the report also present a consistent look to the report.

Please refer to the attached image which may help understand the problem.
[Please see this for further details](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=396407)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by!
Go to Cross Tab Expert and ,Customize Style And select desired row and then check Suppress SubTotals in group options.

Comment: Is there any option to do the same thing conditionally? Here I wish to suppress the sub totals (or whole total) if there is only one record in sub-data (or overall data) in the crosstab.
If there is only one record in sub-data then it doesn’t look good just to repeat the same row in totals / subtotals.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand your question,

If you are using the built-in Cross-Tab object, then rows/columns will drop automatically if there is no data to populate a full row or column.  This is standard behaviour of the object.

If you are mimicking a cross-tab using groups or rows, you can conditionally suppress either group or row based on a formula.  This can be done in the Section Expert using the option Suppress (No Drill-down) by clicking on the "formula" symbol.

If I misunderstand, then please explain again.